# Hedge error - Willmot and Ahmad

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-processes, delta, hedge, stochastic-discount

I'm currently reading the paper: Willmot and Ahmad: Which free lunch would you like today, Sir? Delta Heding, volatility arbitrage.
In case 1: They delta hedge with the actual volatility, by going long in the option and shorting delta. There is one part of their derivation of the guarenteed profit that's confusing my quiet a bit.
The specific step is:
$$dV^i-dV^a -r(V^i-V^a)dt = e^{rt}d(e^{-rt}(V^i- V^a))$$
Can anybody explain this part of the equation?

Comment: Is your question why the equality holds in the equation you wrote?

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite understand how the two sides equal each other.

Comment: So I'm assuming that we are discounting the value $$dV^i$$ and $$dV^a$$. However, I can't get from the left side to the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
d \left(e^{-rt} \left(V^i - V^a \right)\right) &= \left(d e^{-rt} \right) \left(V^i-V^a \right) + e^{-rt} d(V^i - V^a)\\
&= (-e^{-rt} r dt) (V^i - V^a) + e^{-rt} (dV^i - dV^a) \\
&= e^{-rt} [ -r (V^i - V^a)dt + (dV^i - dV^a) ]
\end{align}

So multiplying everything by $e^{rt}$ gives the result.